# pytz US/Eastern converting timestamps back and forth

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, timezone, pytz

From [time and date website](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/new-york-state):

```
Generalized Time Zone in New York
ET  Eastern Time    UTC -5:00 / -4:00   Wed, 11:42:33

Time Zone Currently Being Used in New York
UTC -5  EST Eastern Standard Time   New York    Wed, 11:42:33

Time Zone Not Currently Being Observed in New York
UTC -4  EDT Eastern Daylight Time   10 Mar 2019
```

So basically New York time is EST or EDT depending on which period of the year we are currently on due to the DayLight timesaving.

***When using US/Eastern in pytz, does it refer to ET, EST or EDT?. Does it take into consideration the EST/EDT time change?***

I am using this code to get timestamps for the beginning and end of the day of a given date in Eastern Time:

```py
    import datetime
    import pytz

    session = datetime.datetime.strptime('26/02/2019', '%d/%m/%Y')
    exchange_tz = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
    session_localized = exchange_tz.localize(session)

    _period1 = int((session_localized - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=exchange_tz)).total_seconds())
    _period2 = int((session_localized - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=exchange_tz)).total_seconds()) + 24*60*60

    >>> _period1
    1551139200
    >>> _period2
    1551225600
```

I am not 100% sure that those timestamps have been properly generated. Because when I try to convert them back to localized datetimes I get 1 hour of difference:

```
    _exchange_tz = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
    _exchange_ts = _exchange_tz.localize( datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1551139200) )

    >>> str(_exchange_ts)
    '2019-02-26 01:00:00-05:00'
```

Which as far as I understand, it shall be `2019-02-26 00:00:00`. What am I doing wrong?

I have also read in [pytz documentation](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) that `normalize()` function shall be used when doing arithmetics covering, but I am not sure if this apply to this case or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When using `US/Eastern` in pytz, does it refer to ET, EST or EDT?. Does it take into consideration the EST/EDT time change?

These are IANA (aka TZDB, Olson, etc.) time zone identifiers.  `US/Eastern` is a link/alias to `America/New_York`.  Both correctly model the history of the US Eastern time zone, including EST or EDT depending on when they are applicable.

Regarding your example, the timestamp `1551139200` equates to `2019-02-26T00:00:00Z` (UTC).  In US Eastern Time, that's `2019-02-25T19:00:00-05:00`.  That should be the result you get.  You would first need to localize the input value to UTC (or in the case of UTC, you can assign `tzinfo=pytz.utc` safely).  Then use the `astimezone` function to convert to `US/Eastern`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. However I have used `localize` instead of `tzinfo=exchange_tz` and I get the same timestamps and still have the same issue while trying to convert that timestamp back to US/Eastern

Comment: Updated my answer.  It's two steps: first make the datetime "aware" that it is in UTC, then convert it to Eastern time.  Otherwise you're incorrectly asserting that it's already in Eastern time instead of UTC.  (Unix timestamps are *always* in terms of UTC).

Comment: (Sorry if I'm not directly answering your question - your first block of code has a few things that are difficult to follow, and don't seem related to the second block.)

Comment: The first block of code generates timestamps, that they are later used to call a webservice. The webservice then respond with data for that range defined by two timestamps. Your comment that all timestamps are ALWAYS (it is a strong proposition ALWAYS) UTC is making me double check everything again (the API I am calling is not documented).

Comment: Numeric timestamps, like `1551139200` are always UTC, or should be anyway - unless someone is artificially (incorrectly) adjusting them.  Also the `Z` at the end of an ISO8601 formatted string indicates UTC.  If you just have some date/time value, and it's not in either of those formats, then you have to be aware of its time zone in some other manner.

Comment: With your answer I have narrowed down the issue. I need to understand how to create the timestamp for 00:00 in US/Eastern Time. I have opened a related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54912487/get-timestamp-for-27-02-2019-0000-in-python-using-pytz-and-datetime