# Get timestamp for 27/02/2019 00:00 US/Eastern in python using pytz and datetime

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, timestamp, pytz

I have the following string:

```
27/02/2019
```

As it is known in the program that those dates correspond to NY time zone, I would like to get the timestamp corresponding to:

```
27/02/2019 00:00 US/Eastern
```

I have tried:

```py
import datetime
import pytz

exchange_tz = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
_period1 = datetime.datetime(2019,2,27)
_period1_localized = exchange_tz.localize(_period1)
_period1_ts = int((_period1_localized - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=exchange_tz)).total_seconds()) 

>>> _period1_ts
1551225600
```

But this gives the timestamp corresponding to:

```
27/02/2019 00:00 UTC
```

I have checked that `1551225600` timestamp corresponds to `27/02/2019 00:00 UTC` and not to `27/02/2019 00:00 US/Eastern` using this service:

```
https://www.epochconverter.com/
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you converting the timestamp into the date shown? We need an [mcve].

Comment: I am getting 1551225600 which as far as I know it corresponds to 27/02/2019 00:00 UTC time, which is NOT 27/02/2019 00:00 US/Eastern time. That is minimal, complete and verificable.

Comment: I don't see anywhere on that website where one can specify a specific timezone to which the "human date" should be converted to—so I don't agree that's an authoritative test to use for verification.

Comment: Timestamps are UTC -as far as I know- if you enter the timestamp generated by the code in the website you will get the timestamp with timezone stated in the question. Anyway I found the issue myself. I am sure there are more "authoritative" ways of converting a timestamp to a timezone based human readable date. Feel free to contribute providing one.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case it helps others, I found the error was located here:

```
_period1_ts = int((_period1_localized - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=exchange_tz)).total_seconds())
```

It shall use UTC timezone for the EPOCH time:

```
_period1_ts = int((_period1_localized - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=pytz.utc)).total_seconds())
```

By doing that you get `1551243600` as timestamp, which corresponds to `Wednesday, 27 February 2019 05:00:00 UTC` which is effectively `27/02/2019 00:00 US/Eastern time`

The above code with this correction can be used to get a timestamp from a localized datetime.